# Do leaves grow larger by adding cells at the centre or at the edge?

Tags: cell-biology, botany

I'm writing a paper on wrinkling of plant leaves. For biological and physical background information, I would like to know whether leaves grow by adding cells at the edge, at the center or in a completely different way. Since I need to confirm any information I get, please do not write opinions or guesses. It would be great if someone could find a reliable source with link since all my researches didn't lead to a good answer to this question.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Biology SE! **Homework questions** are off-topic on Biology **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. For more information see our [homework policy](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework).

Comment: Hello, I think you misunderstood my request. I'm currently writing my bachelor thesis in physics and thought that some biological context in the introduction would be nice. Since I do not understand most of the literature in biology, I would be glad if someone could explain in easy words how plant leaves grow. If my question is still inappropriate, feel free to close or delete.

Comment: i am not a plant biologist to give a full-scale answer, but, generally, the cells at the tip and edges of a leaf are the oldest, whereas the cells at the base of the leaf are the youngest. In many, but not all plants, leaves grow from basal leaf meristem, a tissue containing plant stem cells that divide and differentiate into leave cells.

Answer (score 1):

Plant leaves develop from leaf primordium or meristem tissue (this tissue has special properties that allow it to continue dividing to make more more cells, i.e. stem cells - not stem cells like cells in the stem but the technical term 'stem cells). Because of the hormone balances to maintain this division property the meristem tissue will remain close to the stem or branch of the plant at the base of the leaf whilst the new cells added to the leaf slowly move outwards.
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1369526616300929